# About "Improved Dijkstra Algorithm" Paper

Tags: algorithm, vector, constraints, shortest-path, dijkstra

I want to ask a few questions about the algorithm in this paper.

https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9208/65aee7b072c054afa628ba413adda6f3e962.pdf

You may wonder why I don't ask the authors directly, actually I have, but unfortunately, I've got no response and I couldn't find direct emails to the authors.

[image: Algorithm Steps]

You can see the core formula (8) of the algorithm.

- d(n)  = weight value from starting point to current node
- r(n)  = constraint function
- ɷ   = weighted value denoting the impact factor
- θn  = angle between vector that consists of nodes from starting point to current node[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wDLe.png) and vector that consist of nodes from starting point to end point[2]

The steps said that to obtain the best nodes, all subsequent nodes vp (open list) will be compared to satisfy the constraint function above.

What I don't understand is:

1. Regarding the θn vectors, I don't really understand says, we have a graph with nodes 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10. Suppose we start at node 1 and end at node 10, currently we have traversed node 1,2,4,5 (current node= 5). So for [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wDLe.png) it's supposed to be closed list (List of traversed optimal node) and the vector is v= {1,2,4,5}. Then, for [2], it's supposed to be v= {1,2,4,5,..,10}. How is that possible? For what I know, to find vector angle both vectors must have the same amount of nodes and it's weird since nodes between 5 and 10 haven't traversed yet, so it's not possible to use it. So, from my thinking, the vectors is supposed to be v[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wDLe.png) = {1,5} and v[2] = {1,10}, but I wonder if that's even right.
2. About the step 3 of the algorithm, I wonder about the choosing of the best node? I can't understand the meaning of satisfying here since I can't find what condition does the compared nodes need, so it could satisfy the constraint function. Is D(n) must be the smallest or biggest among the compared list or what?

I hope anyone could answer this, and I hope this reach the author too, thanks.

Comment: Angle between the nodes?  Are they assuming the graph represents some sort of geometry?  If so, why are they comparing against Dijkstra's instead of A\*?

Comment: Wait, so this has something to do with A*?

Comment: I did not read the paper,  but from a quick scan they are comparing Dijkstra's, an algorithm that works on arbitrary graphs, to their new algorithm that assumes the nodes have known "angles" between them.  This is similar to the use-cases of A\*, which assumes the nodes have known minimum-distances between them.

Comment: I see, thank you for your answer