# Angle between nodes vector in R using igraph

Tags: r, algorithm, vector, graph, angle

Currently I'm using R igraph to build certain shortest path algorithm but certain constraint function is used in this paper, and it's use angle between nodes.

[About "Improved Dijkstra Algorithm" Paper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44592293/about-improved-dijkstra-algorithm-paper)

```
> el <- matrix(nc=3, byrow=TRUE, c(1,2,1, 1,3,1, 1,4,1, 1,5,1, 1,6,1, 1,7,1, 4,8,1, 4,9,1, 4,10,1, 9,11,1 ) )
> g2 <- add_edges(make_empty_graph(11), t(el[,1:2]), weight=el[,3])
> plot(g2)
```

[image]

Let's say i want to find angle between vector with nodes `vect1 = (n[[1]],n[3])` and `vect2 = (n[[1]],n[10])`

I use this code to find the angle

```
>angle2 <- function(M,N){
    atan2(N[2],N[1]) - atan2(M[2],M[1]) 
}
```

with M = vect1 and N = vect2

There is a result, but it doesn't turns out good. Instead of the nodes coordinates, it uses the nodes id (ex: `vect(N[[1]],N[3]) = vect(1,3)`). I realized this recently, it's because I used function V (vector).

Examples of (wrong) result, using above codes and graph:

- vect(1,2) & vect (1,11) = 0.3729877
- vect(1,3) & vect (1,11) = 0.2310907
- vect(1,4) & vect (1,11) = 0.1543188
- vect(1,5) & vect (1,11) = 0.1067357
- vect(1,6) & vect (1,11) = 0.07448879
- vect(1,7) & vect (1,11) = 0.05123717

Are there any other ways to determine coordinates of the vectors of nodes in in R igraph?

Comment: paper link is missing

Comment: you can get node positions by setting a `?layout`